# Geometric view of translation of a vector by some other vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In linear algebra,

The parametric vector equation $x=t$ $\mathbf v$ represents a line say $L$ through the vector $\mathbb v$ (in $\mathbb{R^2}$), then the parametric equation $p$ + $t$ $\mathbf v$ represents a line through $p$ parallel to $L$, for which i can check the condition for being parallel easily from the equal slopes condition. we say each vector $t$$\mathbf v$ is translated by $p$ to $p$ + $t$$\mathbf v$

How can i check the same for equations with vectors in $\mathbb{R^3}$ (**can be a line or plane**) and vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$. Is there any generalization for  parallelism, defined for vector equations involving vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The conditions you wrote, as long as you use vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, give parallel lines in $n$-dimensional space.

Comment: @Michael Burr yes, but the parametric equation need not always be $p$ + $t$$\mathbb v$. Example being a plane spanned by $u$ and $v$ like with vector equation as $s$$\mathbf u$ + $t$$\mathbf v$. geometrically, parallelism for two planes is a cross product of normal vectors to the planes being 0. i wanted it know how it translates in terms of vector equations involving vectors both in $\mathbb {R^3}$ and $\mathbb {R^n}$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr In short, what i want is a parametric vector equation for a plane parallel to plane ( which i cant have with vectors in $\mathbb {R^2}$ and a generalization to vector equations involving vectors in  $\mathbb {R^n}$ if there is any. Hope i was able to convey my question properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you have vectors $\vec{v}_1,\cdots,\vec{v}_k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Then, if the vectors are independent, 
$$
t_1\vec{v}_1+\cdots+t_k\vec{v}_k
$$
spans a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  To create a parallel $k$-flat, you just need to shift the subspace by $\vec{p}$,
$$
\vec{p}+t_1\vec{v}_1+\cdots+t_k\vec{v}_k.
$$